# Converting String to Object parameter

Tags: java

The program is a text engine that takes in a text file and analyzes it.

```
public Word findFirst(String text) throws SearchableException, ContentNotLoadedException {
    for(int i = 0;i<words.size();i++) {
        if(text.equals(words.get(i).text)) {
            return words.get(i).text;
        }
    }   
}
```

This is a method that is supposed to return the first instance of a word that matches the input "text." "words" is the array list that loads all the words. I get an error of "can't convert from string to word" in my return statement and while I understand the error, I can't think of an alternative way to go about doing this?

```
public class Word {

public final String text;
public final int position;
public final int length;
public final int line;
public final int positionInLine;

 public Word(String text, int position, int length, int line, int positionInLine) {
    this.text = text;
    this.position = position;
    this.length = length;
    this.line = line;
    this.positionInLine = positionInLine;
}
```

This is the Word class in question.

Edit:I am unable to change the method signature or Word class in any way.

Comment: `public String findFirst...`?

Comment: why not just "return words.get(i)" instead of "return words.get(i).text";

Comment: I swear I tried that out earlier and it didn't work, but now it does..... thank you very much Spara!

Comment: It's ok bro :D This will happens a lot in programming world! I will make my comment as a answer for you now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `return words.get(i)` instead of `return words.get(i).text`.

```
public Word findFirst(String text) throws SearchableException, ContentNotLoadedException {
    for(int i = 0;i<words.size();i++) {
        if(text.equals(words.get(i).text)) {
            return words.get(i);
        }
    }   
return null;
}
```

Comment: What does it do if you don't find the text? This currently doesn't compile because not all paths return a value.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on java-8 you can use this to return the first String that matches:

```
public String findFirst(String text) throws SearchableException {
    return words.stream().filter(i -> i.text.equals(text)).findFirst().get().text;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to return the entire object you can use :

```
public Word findFirst(String text) throws SearchableException {
    return words.stream().filter(i -> i.text.equals(text)).findFirst().get();
}
```

Comment: the question was not how to rewrite the loops, it was about type conversion

Comment: I'm curious if this method is much more efficient. With the authors original code, once a match is found the method returns but your implementation first filters the whole list then returns the first element in the list. If there are 1000 matches I feel like the OP's code will run faster.

Comment: That's not how filter works. It is almost the same as OP's code, just that we are using streams. As soon as the filter condition evaluates to true the iteration of the loop will stop and the corresponding instance will be returned due to `findFirst()`. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--)

Comment: The second example doesn't compile because findFirst() returns an Optional instead of a Word.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException - Good catch! Missed out the `.get()`

Answer (score 1):

Actually the return type of the method is `Word` so when your `return` gives a `String` it can't goes from `String` to `Word`.

1. To fix this, change return type to `String`

   ```
   public String findFirst(String text) throws SearchableException, ContentNotLoadedException {
       for(int i = 0;i<words.size();i++) {
           if(text.equals(words.get(i).text)) {
               return words.get(i).text;
           }
       }        
   }
   ```
2. Or return the whole `Word` object

   ```
   public Word findFirst(String text) throws SearchableException, ContentNotLoadedException {
       for(int i = 0;i<words.size();i++) {
           if(text.equals(words.get(i).text)) {
               return words.get(i);
           }
       }        
   }
   ```

---

Tip to simplify the loop

1. `foreach` loop

   ```
   for (Word word : words) {
       if (text.equals(word.text)) {
           return word.text;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Stream

   ```
   return words.stream().map(Word::getText).filter(text::equals).findFirst().orElseThrow(()->new SearchableException());
   ```

Comment: The Stream example forces you to think about what happens when the text is not found. What about the loop implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot change the method signature you have to return an Word instance. So you should not return Word.text but the Word instance directly or a new one.